# Multible checkbox selection in ACF does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields

**my values**

```
s1 : red
s2 : blue
s3 : green
```

i want to select s1 and s2

```
update_field( "eigenschaften_sicherheit", array("s2", "s1"), 5268 );
```

this code set only the latest `s2` value and not the `s1`

for exampe this code will only select `s3`

```
update_field( "eigenschaften_sicherheit", array("s1", "s3"), 5268 );
```

The [docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) say this

```
// save a checkbox or select value
$field_key = "field_1234567";
$value = array("red", "blue", "yellow");
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

any ideas whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I'm using the field name, not the field key.

Info:
To see the field key, when editing the field group, click on Screen Options (top right) and check the Field Keys option.